# How to simulate "tab key" in iOS SwiftUI Application?

Tags: ios, swiftui, focus

I am currently working on an iOS SwiftUI Application that has multiple of rows programmatically generated text fields.

At the moment I am struggling to implement a way for users to move quickly between text fields.

When I run the simulator and press the tab key on the keyboard this does exactly the behavior I am trying to implement.

Is there a way to implement this "tab key press" within the SwiftUI application?

Answer (score 0):

Thus far I havent been able to find a straight answer to my question (replicate tab button functionality) but I have found a workaround.

**Parent View**

```
struct ParentView: View {

    @FocusState var focusVar: String?

    var body: some View {

    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        ForEach(dataset) { currRow in
           ChildView(currRow: currRow, focusVar: _focusVar)
        }
      }
      .toolbar {
          ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
              print("back pressed")
              lastFocus()
             }) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
            .imageScale(.large)
            }.padding(.trailing)
            
            Button(action: {
              print("forward pressed")
              nextFocus()
             }) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
            .imageScale(.large)
            }
       }
}
```

**Child View**

```
struct ChildView: View {
   @FocusState var focusVar: String?
   var currRow: [Array]

   var body: some View {
      TextField(...)
         .focused($focusVar, equals: String(currRow.id)+"CID")

   }
}
```